# How to add color on gridview's horizontalSpacing and verticalSpacing?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to add a line between each items in GridView.Now I add horizontalSpacing and verticalSpacing in GridView,but I hope my item's background and gridview's background is the same color,just use the lines to distinguish each items.Like the following picture.
http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2855226622

My gridview Xml is

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/bout_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get by

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

and the GridView items must to have another color, in this way you can get the effect you want.